# List Item Selected Behavior

Tags: android

When I change the background color of a list item it no longer flashes green when selected.  Is there a way to retain this default behavior when the background is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "green flash" is part of the background. By replacing the background (presumably, with a simple color), you eliminated the flash.

First, consider whether you should be changing the background of a list item. For example, if you are doing all of the list items this way, perhaps the `ListView` should have the background color.

If that does not help, you need to make the background be a `StateListDrawable` with the appropriate states.

Comment: Your response was helpful, thank you.  The background for each item in this list can be configured via an xml file brought in by http when the app starts up.  I found a way to do what I want using an onTouchListner.  Not sure if that's the best way.

Answer (score 1):

u can set the background resource for the view with

```
setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.menuitem_background);
```

and get the desired effect